# DB2 Merge and effect of simultaneous inserts to the table on ROWCOUNT

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have to update the table in batches. I first select records in dataset , process them and send the xml constructed from dataset to stored proc.
I have a stored procedure which has xml as input parameter. It updates the table using merge query as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_UPDATE(IN RECORDS XML, OUT ROWSUPDATED INTEGER)
BEGIN
DECLARE RCOUNT INTEGER;
MERGE INTO TARGET_TABLE AS T
USING (SELECT X.* FROM 
XMLTABLE('$d/Root/Record' passing RECORDS as "d"
COLUMNS 
        "A" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'a',
        "B" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'b',
        "C" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'c',
        "D" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'd',
        "E" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'e',
        "F" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'f' 
) AS X) AS S
ON T.FCOL=S."F"
WHEN MATCHED AND T.ACOL=0 THEN
UPDATE
SET
T.ACOL=1,
T.BCOL=XT."B",
T.COL=XT."C"
GET DIAGNOSTICS RCOUNT=ROWCOUNT;
SET ROWSUPDATED=RCOUNT;
END
```

This procedure is being called until all the records get updated. New records get inserted to the target table at the same time by other applications.I have to update both old and newely inserted records as above by setting some column value to 1. 
The problem is ROWSUPDATED value is not correct. Suppose I'had sent 10 xml records for update, ROWSUPDATED values would be less than 10. Why the ROWCOUNT variable is not giving me proper count? Is my stored proc failing to update records in presence of continuous inserts or it's just false value by ROWCOUNT?..Is ROWCOUNT safest way to get the count of rows updated by merge query in presence of inserts in the same table?

Comment: I'm assuming that `ROWCOUNT` is likely to be the total rows updated (please check documentation on this - my version doesn't have `MERGE`), and that there are some 'matched' rows where `T.ACOL <> 0` (hence, rows are not updated).

Comment: It is not possible that "when matched" can fail. I'm selecting records from table with T.ACOL=0. I'm processing them in application and sending them again for update. The problem is ROWCOUNT gives me incorrect value for merge query when the rows I selected in first step were recently inserted in table.